# How could I repack a jar file with all of its dependencies?

Tags: java, import, jar, dependencies, export

I am developing an application which is supposed to run standalone. However, this project involves a .jar file which contains a lot of dependencies, and if I simply distribute this .jar file with the application, it won't work.

I wonder if there is any way in which I could unpack the file, add the dependencies and repack it again? I hope there are some automatic mechanism for this, since the manual process could take hours, and there might be other referenced jar files.

P.S. I am using Eclipse, but since I am going to deploy this project with Web Start, exporting the project with the build-in export tool might not be a good idea since my attempts all ended up with [ClassNotFoundException, so I suspect I might have to pack the project into several jars.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612556/java-web-start-classnotfoundexception-when-running)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Easiest way to merge a release into one jar-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81260/java-easiest-way-to-merge-a-release-into-one-jar-file)

Comment: @Robin In this case the jar is not runnable. However, I believe the problem is very similar. But with answers, I cannot delete my question now.

Comment: Runnable or not, merging the jar files is the same thing, just no main class declared.

Comment: Please note that in the case that several original jar files contain the same filename with different content (mostly content of META-INF, like MANIFEST.MF or Spring's schema handler declaration), these files need to be merged somehow, or else you might get strange errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [jar jar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/). It sounds like it will do what you need.

Comment: Um... Jar-Jar Links... Being a Die-hard Star Wars fan, I serious doubt anything with such a name can function properly. Just kidding, will check:)

Comment: Star wars aside: I've actually used it professionally. It is quite established/mature.

Answer (score 24):

Repacking an unpacked JAR is a little frustrating because of the folder structure

When unpacking with:

```
jar xvf JAR_NAME.jar
```

you get a `JAR_NAME/` folder

**To repack the JAR:**

- remove old jar

  `rm JAR_NAME.jar`
- get inside the folder

  `cd JAR_NAME`
- pack the jar referencing the parent folder

  `jar cf ../JAR_NAME.jar *`

and you will end up with the `JAR_NAME.jar` in the parent folder, where the original was unpacked from, without the first folder level you would get if you had packed the folder itself.

Comment: Works perfectly. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: for me, the jar is not extracted to `JAR_NAME` folder but in place

Answer (score 6):

For Spring Boot 2.1.9.RELEASE I managed to unpack and re-pack the fat jar like this:
Move into the folder with the jar file.

Extract jar file

```
jar xvf app.jar
```

Remove old jar file

```
rm app.jar
```

Create new jar file in parent dir

```
jar cmf0 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF ../app.jar  *
```

m ... use a specific manifest-file

0 ... deactivates compression, which circumvents that the dependencies(jar-files) are compressed

Documentation can also be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes unpacking and packing will irritate you sometimes especially in Linux environments like Ubuntu,

Before unpacking make sure your Java_Home and path is exported to the folder as below :
In your home directory, you will most likely have a file called .bashrc. Go to the end of the file and add the following

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path to your JDK install e.g. /opt/jdk>
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This sets your JAVA_HOME environment variable - commonly used by Java-based applications. It then prepends that directory to your PATH variable. The operating system understands PATH as a list of the parent directories of executable files.

Now unpack `jar xvf JAR_NAME.jar`

Packing back`jar cf JAR_NAME.jar *`

Comment: This alters the MANIFEST.MF file. How can I repack a jar without altering the manifest file?

Comment: @ChrisF, please try options to provide required manifest as: 
`jar options jar-file [manifest-file]`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Export runnable jar" in eclipse? It should works for you.

Take a look at this picture:
 [image: picture]

Comment: Yes but I had problems when I tried to deploy the project (see the P.S. part), so I gave up this method.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the previous comment that the jar file I am trying to repack is not runnable:(